# Deploy Microsoft Portals

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

We are just configuring our first Microsoft CRM Portal using the Portals Add-In.

We are doing this in our sandbox, obviously. Question: How do we deploy this to our production system? As far as I see, most of the data is not saved in a solution but in entity records. Is there a practical way to deploy the stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll want to use the Portal Records Mover in the XRMToolbox. It will allow you to export/import the relevant records for the Portal.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmtools/archive/2017/06/13/new-xrmtoolbox-plugin-portal-records-mover

Alternatively, you can use the Configuration Migration tool (available in the SDK NuGet package) to move the records. I prefer the Portal Records Mover because it provides more granular control and supports updates without overwriting.

Comment: As of 25 Aug 2020 the Portal Records Mover has a bug for me that stops me using it: https://github.com/MscrmTools/MscrmTools.PortalRecordsMover/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Nicknow use **Configuration Migration** and **Portal Records Mover**.
I would do the first transfer with the **Configuration Migration** and continue with **Portal Records Mover** where you can filter records that were updated on a given time frame.

You can also build your own **SSIS package** to filter the modified records and move them on the productive system.